# how to click on image make it zoom in popup windows in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have graph image i want that when i click on image the image should zoom in popup windows so that it can been seen easily.

Comment: do you want a pop like [this](http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html)

Comment: yes like popup windows with zoomed image

Comment: I think you should Google a bit. Try to get the code running. If you fail post your code here. People will help. Try get on moving using this [plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a link to your image with a `target="_blank"` attribute and a `href` attribute that point to your zommed image URL.

Comment: this is to provide link but how i will open this in popup window

Comment: That wath target is for (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-target)